# Scraping Yahoo Finance after recent change Oc 2019

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

symbol = 'AAPL'

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/balance-sheet?p=' + symbol



page = requests.get(url)

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

tableHeaders = tree.xpath('//*[@class="D(tbhg)"]//span') 

Headers = []
for Header in tableHeaders:
    Headers.append(Header.text)

df = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=Headers,index=[1])


Xpath1 = "//span[contains(.,'"+item1+"')]/parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::div"


item1 = 'Long Term Debt'
row1 = []
row1.append(item1)



rowvalues1 = tree.xpath(Xpath1) 

for value1 in rowvalues1:
    row1.append(value1.text)

Xpath1 = Xpath1+"/span"
Childvalues1 = tree.xpath(Xpath1) 
j=0
for i in range(len(row1)):
    if(row1[i]==None):
        row1[i] =Childvalues1[j].text
        j=j+1



df.loc[1] = row1



df=df.fillna(0)
df[df=='-'] ='0'

long_term_debt=float(str(df.iloc[0,4]).replace(',',''))
```

When I run AAPL symbol I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-fe5e79eabd51> in <module>
     57 df[df=='-'] ='0'
     58 
---> 59 long_term_debt=float(str(df.iloc[0,4]).replace(',',''))
     60 
--
   2007         l = len(ax)
   2008         if key >= l or key < -l:
-> 2009             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
   2010 
   2011     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
```

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

I can't run value extracted from `df`   as in case of AAPL there is no year  2015 for the company. Yahoo finance closed that year for this company however for other companies there is year 2015.

What I can do to remove such error for this specific year and symbol.  I tried using 'None' in function for long-term variable however it does not work.  Any idea how to approach this case?

The formula tried to use :

```
def debt():
    if df.iloc[0,4]== None : return 0
    else: float(str(df.iloc[0,4]).replace(',',''))
```

However it does not work

Comment: // table no longer points to what you need. you will have to change the xpath. what information are you trying to scrape.

Comment: I am trying to get financial statements table in Dataframe. How can I get it? as other sections I can retrieve but not this one.

Comment: Its not a table anymore. we will have to use custom xpath to create a table with required fields and feed as data frame.  Panda may have some other ways to do this.

Comment: Could you please share what function I should use? I do not have such experience only with the above method. For example, after table = tree.xpath('//table') ? It extracts but how then to convert to panda data frame. What other way you advise to use?

Comment: I just posted a sample answer with table headers. You can read the desired rows in similar way & add it to dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install YahooFinancials library to your python.

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

symbol = 'ORCL'

url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + symbol + '/balance-sheet?p=' + symbol



page = requests.get(url)

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

tableHeaders = tree.xpath('//*[@class="D(tbhg)"]//span') 

Headers = []
for Header in tableHeaders:
    Headers.append(Header.text)

df = pd.DataFrame()
#Adding columns
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=Headers,index=[1])
item5 = 'Inventory'
row5 = []
row5.append(item5)

Xpath = "//span[contains(.,'"+item5+"')]/parent::div/parent::div/following-sibling::div"

rowvalues5 = tree.xpath(Xpath) # identify all 4 high level nodes
# This will store the high level node values, but store 'None' if value is not present.
for value5 in rowvalues5:
    row5.append(value5.text)
 #if the value is None, we are going to fetch to next level node values using /span   
Xpath = Xpath+"/span"
Childvalues = tree.xpath(Xpath) #Fetch low level nodes
j=0
for i in range(len(row5)):
    if(row5[i]==None):
        row5[i] =Childvalues[j].text
        j=j+1


df.loc[1] = row5

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you. But this only scraps the concrete variable, how to make it to scrap the whole table for all variables and all years? I am not programmer I am finance specialist and my scrapping skills are limited so thereby would appreciate any help and hint.

Comment: I think its possible to create a complete table dynamically without hard coding the line item variable. but that would take some effort to program. If you know what are the variable you would require, we can make a list & create a loop to scrape only those values from this page.

Comment: Ok thank you I got it. Is it possible to extract everything at once without giving specific values ? For example, the above code I provided, in the past used to give me the whole table for different symbols upon my request as for symbol the value might differ and it will give false values. I have one library I applied and the same happened when I used variables. Is there any way to keep such flexibility and simplicity?  as the tables in https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/cash-flow?p=FB gives all variable in the same order so no index positioning error. Would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. there is a whole library called YahooFinancials and this should give you what you need with little effort. see my updated answer

Comment: Yes I know this library this is the library I was talking to you. When I put in pandas data frame and use iloc to get specific values, the values differ for different companies whereas the website provides the same for every tickers.

Comment: I followed your example and tried to get 'Weighted average shares outstanding' from income statement however it does not show numbers. There are sub variables of 'Weighted average shares outstanding' 'Basic' and 'Diluted'. Could you please explain what I am doing wrong? I made changes in my answer above. I will appreciate your help to get the values.

Comment: See updated answer for Weighted average shares outstanding' - 'Basic' and 'Diluted' variables

Comment: Hi again. Could you please help to understand the issue with the table you helped me. I want to extract value form the panda data frame and convert to float and I did using 'float(df.iloc[0,2]) ' however it shows an error and says it can't be converted to float. What is the problem here? I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: The value string has comma on it. you have to remove it before converting to float. try this - float(str(df.iloc[0,2]).replace(',',''))

Comment: Hi again ))). I tried to use your method to scrap a variable from Yahoo finance , however it gives an error when entering different symbols. Could you please answer the question I asked above. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Its possible that xpath could be different for other symbols. which symbol are you trying now? May i also ask you create a new question as this is a different issue.

Comment: See updated answer. this code is now factoring any None Values. If the value is none, it will fetch it from the child elements. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey I tried to run your code but in my environment it does not run and gives an error : df.loc[1] = row5  : cannot set a row with mismatched columns. What can it be?

Comment: sorry. i did not change the url. I have updated it now. This logic should work for any line item in the table on the balance sheet table. you can replace 'Inventory' with any other line item on this table.

Comment: Het thank you I works. However another issue arises when I change the symbol for AAPL for example. The issue cause for some stocks there is no year 2015. How can I solve the problem not to receive such errors in the future? Could you please look at ,y question area I changed the code and inserted your answer but symbol changed and variable long-term debt inserted. Any help would be great.

Comment: I am able to get the data using above code without any errors. The finding of headers & the for loop is dynamic. The loop runs through the length of the columns, so even if 1 year is missing, it should take care of it without errors. However if you are trying to merge this data with your existing data frame, you may be missing a whole column. so you may see errors in merging it. My suggestion is to use None as value for missing ones.

Comment: Thank you for time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Guys this work with the latest changes in yahoo finance

```
def get_page(url):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Referrer': 'https://google.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36'
    }

    return requests.get(url, headers=headers)

def parse_rows(table_rows):
    parsed_rows = []

    for table_row in table_rows:
        parsed_row = []
        el = table_row.xpath("./div")

        none_count = 0

        for rs in el:
            try:
                (text,) = rs.xpath('.//span/text()[1]')
                parsed_row.append(text)
            except ValueError:
                parsed_row.append(np.NaN)
                none_count += 1

        if (none_count < 4):
            parsed_rows.append(parsed_row)

    return pd.DataFrame(parsed_rows)



def scrape_table(url):

    page = get_page(url);
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    table_rows = tree.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'D(tbr)')]")
    assert len(table_rows) > 0
    df = parse_rows(table_rows)
    return df



bs = scrape_table('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + tickers[0] + '/balance-sheet?p=' + tickers[0])
bs[1]=bs[1].str.replace(',', '')
bs[2]=bs[2].str.replace(',', '')
bs[3]=bs[3].str.replace(',', '')
bs[4]=bs[4].str.replace(',', '')
bs=bs.fillna(0)
bs[bs=='-'] ='0'

ic = scrape_table('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + tickers[0] + '/financials?p=' + tickers[0])
ic[1]=ic[1].str.replace(',', '')
ic[2]=ic[2].str.replace(',', '')
ic[3]=ic[3].str.replace(',', '')
ic[4]=ic[4].str.replace(',', '')
ic[5]=ic[5].str.replace(',', '')
ic=ic.fillna(0)
ic[ic=='-'] ='0'

cf = scrape_table('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + tickers[0] + '/cash-flow?p=' + tickers[0])
cf[1]=cf[1].str.replace(',', '')
cf[2]=cf[2].str.replace(',', '')
cf[3]=cf[3].str.replace(',', '')
cf[4]=cf[4].str.replace(',', '')
cf[5]=cf[5].str.replace(',', '')
cf=cf.fillna(0)
cf[cf=='-'] ='0'
```

if you want to get value for revenue for the 2019:

```
revenue2019=float(ic.iloc[1,1])
```